# how to call navigation bar in magento 2.2.6

Tags: navigation, topmenu, magento2.2.6

How to call navigation main menu in magento2.2? please let me know.

I follow this code for our custom header in default.xml file.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="myheader" template="html/myheader.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
    <move element="minicart" destination="myheader"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="myheader"/>
    <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="myheader"/>
```

Then echo this elements call in myheader.phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topSearch"); ?>
```

so my i have coming menu toggle but not display navigation bar please let me know how we can fix this issue.

Comment: do you want to add top menu, catalog.nav ? or you have custom menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per screenshot https://prnt.sc/laljiy please put "Outfits", "shops" and "sale" category as child of "default category".

Let me know if it works.

Comment: do the need full.

Comment: Good observation +1

Answer (score 0):

you need to add at `default.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="myheader" template="html/myheader.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="minicart" destination="myheader"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="myheader"/>
        <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="myheader"/>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" as="nav" destination="myheader"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And in Phtml you can get at `myheader.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topSearch"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("nav"); ?>
```

Comment: only nav not working "http://prntscr.com/lalh92" please check this screenshot

Comment: I think you you missed some tag in xml Or you need to flush cache.I have put whole code, please try again.

Comment: Remember to flush cache.Above code is tested.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lali6e

Comment: Please check my this screenshot please let me know."http://prntscr.com/lali6e"

Comment: as per screen shot div is created i.e move is working.Do you have any active categories in admin ?

Comment: yes i have 3 category active in admin

Comment: Please check this screenshot "http://prntscr.com/laljiy"